# Is it necessary to close input/output streams created from a socket's IO streams when the socket closes?

Tags: java, sockets

```
  private val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))
  private val out = new PrintWriter(con.getOutputStream(), true)
  try {
    while (true) {
      if (in.readLine() == null)
        throw new IOException("connection reset by peer")
    }
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
  } finally {

    // Is this necessary?
    in.close()
    out.close()

    // Close socket
    con.shutdownInput()
    con.shutdownOutput()
    con.close()
  }
```

If any IO streams or reader/writers is created from socket's input or output stream, is it necessary to close them before or after socket is closed?

Comment: Its a good practice to close them. They will be closed anyway when the socket is closed.

Comment: I agree with Sudhanshu: it is a good practice. Morover, you should use try/catch here too: imagine `in.close()` fails: `out` and `con`remain open.

Comment: Ummm .... this is NOT Java code...

Comment: but it uses java socket and IO classes ;)

Comment: I cannot see the point of the readLine() loop. If it delivers data, you are throwing it away, and if it delivers null it means the peer closed the connection gracefully, *not* that the connection was reset. This code lies to itself.

Comment: @EJP the code is a snippet with large portion removed

Comment: I suggest you remove the exception with the misleading message as well.

Comment: @EJP does connect reset usually trigger IOException on read?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If any IO streams or reader/writers is created from socket's input or output stream, is it necessary to close them before or after socket is closed?

You should close the outermost `OutputStream` or `Writer` you have created from the socket output stream. That will flush the stream and close the socket and its input stream. Closing any other aspect of the socket, such as its direct output stream, its input stream or anything wrapped around it, or the socket itself, accomplishes most but not all of that: specifically, closing the input stream before the output stream as you have in your example *prevents* the output stream being flushed and so can lose data.

Calling `shutdownInput()` or `shutdownOutput()` immediately before a close is always redundant.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Socket Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close%28%29):

> Closing this socket will also close the socket's InputStream and OutputStream.

Of course, any readers/writers your code explicitly opened should also be explicitly closed, but as far as network resources are concerned, they will be released regardless.

As far as the ordering of actions is concerned, the standard rules apply: last to open -> first to close. So definitely close all your readers/writers *before* closing the underlying socket connection.

Comment: thank you. Given that they are automatically closed, I think https://github.com/technomancy/server-socket/blob/master/src/server/socket.clj is outdated.

Comment: That's not answering the OPs whole question - he's also asking what should be done about readers and writers created from those streams.

Comment: I've just studied the source code of `InputStreamReader`, `BufferedReader` and `PrintWriter`. They all `ensureOpen` the underlying stream before doing any actual IO. With the underlying stream closed, (according to my understanding) they become garbage objects and will be GCed.

Comment: @HowardGuo The code in that link isn't 'outdated', it's just highly redundant. The shutdowns were never required, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary in this case, but it does no harm.

However, if you haven't set the "autoFlush" flag in the `PrintWriter` constructor, then if you didn't close or flush the `Writer` before closing the `Socket`, some data might not be sent.  (And if you closed in the wrong order, you could get an exception!)

For readers / input streams this is not a concern.  You've already decided to ignore any buffered input.

---

There is no concern with leaking resources (file descriptors).  If the Socket is closed, all I/O resources are released.  You don't need to call `shutdownInput` or `shutdownOutput` either.  Closing the `Socket` will do that.

Comment: From good practice point of view, do you recommend the reader/writers to be closed explicitly?

Comment: Well ... I wouldn't recommend that.  I don't see any point in doing something that is obviously (to me) redundant.  However, like I said, there's no real harm in doing it.  So if the "best practice" monitors say "JUST DO IT" ... don't argue.  :-)

Comment: Or to put it another way, if you can't figure out if it is necessary or not, closing all streams in the reverse order that they were opened is ... safe.